# Extract cross sections from a plot of multiple spheres in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I know the locations of spheres (center and radius) in a box. I want to extract cross sections. I am able to plot the spheres placed in a cube using the following Matlab code:

```
[X,Y,Z] = sphere;
for SpNum = 1:NumSpheres
    surf( X*Radius(SpNum)+Center(SpNum,1), Y*Radius(SpNum)+Center(SpNum,2), Z*Radius(SpNum)+Center(SpNum,3), ...
    'FaceColor','r' );
%shading interp;
hold on;
end
axis tight; daspect([1 1 1]);
```

In the above code, each sphere could have different radius and they do not overlap (so the centers are also different).

The above code does not however generate cross sections. I want to extract cross sections similar to what we get from say X-ray CT data: a series of images in the Z-direction. I think 'interp2/interp3' and 'slice' functions are the relevant functions, but I am not sure how to use them to generate the cross sections. I would appreciate if anyone could give pointers or provide some sample code for my problem?

-- Thanks in advance.

Update:

I tried using meshgrid to generate the grid points followed by the function F(X,Y,Z) as follows:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100,1:100);
F = zeros(size(X),'uint8');
for SpNum = 1:NumSpheres
    F( sqrt((X - Center(SpNum,1)).^2 + (Y - Center(SpNum,2)).^2 + (Z -     Center(SpNum,3)).^2) <= Radius(SpNum) ) = 1;
end
surf(F);
```

followed by:

```
z = 1;
I = interp3(X, Y, Z, X*Radius(SpNum)+Center(SpNum,1), Y*Radius(SpNum)+Center(SpNum,2), Z*Radius(SpNum)+Center(SpNum,3), z, 'spline');
figure, imshow(I);
```

I know that interp3 is the function to use since it interpolates the values of the function F(X,Y,Z) which represent the spheres at different location within a bounded box (say 1:100, 1:100, 1:100). The interpolated values at particular 'z' (= 1, 2, 3... 100) should give me 100 cross sections (in the form of 2-D images).

The flaw is in the function F itself, since 'surf' throws an error saying that F should be an array - "CData must be an M-by-N matrix or M-by-N-by-3 array".

Can anyone please help.

Comment: This seems as a good time to return to fundamental algebra. The classical way to solve this is as an optimization problem. This can easily be transformed to a matrix equation. For multiple spheres, this can be done for 2 spheres at the time using a for loop. If you Want the points where at least 3 spheres intersect, then just add an extra constraint. "I want the intersection for these two spheres, which is lying on this third sphere"

Comment: Hi Patrik, thanks for your reply. I don't know if I understood it right, but I don't think it is an optimization problem. I know that interp3 is the function to use since it interpolates the values of the function F(X,Y,Z) which represent the spheres at different location within a bounded box (say 0:100, 0:100, 0:100). The interpolated values at particular 'z' (= 1, 2, 3... 100) should give me 100 cross sections (in the form of 2-D images).

Comment: Now I am not sure that I understood your question then. Do you mean that you have a function or do you only have a set of points which together may form a spherical (or elliptical?) shape? If this is the case, then you do not want to know how to find the intersection of a sphere, but the intersection of to lines (or planes) in an image, which is not the same thing. The intersection of a sphere, you get from defining the equation of each sphere and then solve it as an optimization problem. So to say, answer the question: "where do I find the minimum distance between 2 intersecting spheres"

Comment: If you keeps thinking about this you would see that even if you have a fix set of points forming a spherical shape you would still need to solve it with a numerical optimization method. That is what interpolation is really. The interpolation method usually have a criterion that you fulfill, like the least square method. A method like this should probably be preferred in this case since it is better to solve the problem: "what point is closest to this sphere", than using your suggestion and solve the problem: "can I find a sample rate where a point on this sphere equals a point on this sphere"

Comment: An example, think that you have two spheres with radius `pi/2` where the centers are separated by `pi`. These spheres will intersect at exactly an euclidian distance of `pi/2`. However, with your current sample rate, how would you ever find this point. This point not exist for any finite sample rate. There is still not impossible to approximate this point but `interp3` will not have an exact match as you hope for.

Comment: Hi Patrik, thanks for your replies. Either my question was vague or you didn't understand it. Anyway, I figured it and have posted my answer below. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: Ok I am sorry about this. I must have read it wrong since I read "intersection". However, check out my comments on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it. For the benefit of others, here is the code.

```
% A 3-D matrix 'F' which has its value at particular coordinate set to 255 if it belongs to any one of the spheres and 0 otherwise.
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100,1:100);
F = zeros(size(X));
for SpNum = 1:NumSpheres
    F( sqrt((X - Center(SpNum,1)).^2 + (Y - Center(SpNum,2)).^2 + (Z - Center(SpNum,3)).^2) <= Radius(SpNum) ) = 255;        
end
% Extract cross sections from F using interp3 function along the z-axis.
I = zeros(size(X));
for z = 1:100
    I(:,:,z) = interp3(X, Y, Z, F, 1:100, (1:100)', z, 'spline');
end
implay(I,4);
```

You could test and visualize the output by setting Center (a 3-D vector) and Radius of each sphere (some arbitrary NumSpheres) to some random values. The above code will display a window with cross-sections.

Previously, I was trying to use 'surf' to render the spheres which is not right. To render, you have to use the first code snippet. Another mistake I made was using a row vector for the 6th argument instead of column vector.

Hope this helps.

--
Cheers,
Ram.

Comment: This certainly looks good! However, I am not really sure What you have done here. Try To run the code and then compare `F` and `I` (`isequal(F,I)` or `nnz(F-I)`). What you do is to iteratively finds the closest match per layer of the F matrix. The operation can firstly be vectorized in `z`; But more important, since every value in `I` have an exact match in `F`, `interp3` will most likely select that value and return it. Otherwise, if `interp3` would still perform an interpolation the function would have a bad performance if the value in `I` would not be the same as the value in `F`.

Comment: However, for the record, if the resolution were different for `I` and this would work. Just remove the loop and replace it with `I = interp3(X, Y, Z, F, 1:100, (1:100)', 1:100, 'spline');`. Another thing, since the the equation for the radius of the sphere is quadratic the most accurate interpolation method may not be required here. Try the `cubic` option (since there is no second order option) and see if the result is satisfying. Otherwise go back to `spline`. Except for that, if you increase the resolution in `I`, the edge might be a little smeared out along with the spheres face.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the vectorized operation in interp3 function to extract all cross-sections. Yes, you are right, if higher (or different) resolution than in F is desired (which is what I want), interpolation is the solution.